# Ставится ли запятая и почему?

Tags: запятые

Нужна ли запятая и почему в таком предложении: *Я понимаю, что это*.

Я думаю, что здесь изъяснительное предложение, но не уверен в этом. Мне непонятно, где подлежащее и сказуемое.

Answer (score 2):

***Я понимаю, чтО это.***

Это действительно сложноподчиненное предложение с придаточным **изъяснительным,** поэтому запятая ставится.

В этом предложении используется не союз ***что*** (служебное слово), а союзное слово ***что***, которое  одновременно является сказуемым, а ***это*** – подлежащее.

Обратим внимание: ударение падает на союзное слово ***что***

Для сравнения: *Я понимаю, **что** это  прАвда*. Здесь на союз ***что*** ударение не падает.